# Arabic text will display with polyglossia setmainlanguage but not setotherlanguage

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, arabic

As per the title, I can display Arabic text (left to right) with polyglossia's \setmainlanguage but not \setotherlanguage or \setotherlanguages in a body of text - inline, switching to Arabic script displays correctly, but this is unsuitable for a text body, as it maintains the left-to-right alignment. I am using XeLaTeX. The text block displays as a series of squares as when a font is missing characters, and the error `17 Error| Missing number, treated as zero.` is obtained. With \setmainlanguage, everything works as expected. MWE of the working \setmainlanguage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Common},PunctuationSpace=0,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Numbers={Proportional},SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},BoldSlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},SmallCapsFeatures={FakeSlant=0}]{Libertinus Serif}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,ItalicFont=*,Scale=1.75]{Scheherazade}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[short foobar]{long fooooobar}
الديباجة

لما كان الاعتراف بالكرامة المتأصلة في جميع أعضاء الأسرة البشرية وبحقوقهم المتساوية الثابتة هو أساس الحرية والعدل والسلام في العالم.

ولما كان تناسي حقوق الإنسان وازدراؤها قد أفضيا إلى أعمال همجية آذت الضمير الإنساني، وكان غاية ما يرنو إليه عامة البشر انبثاق عالم يتمتع فيه الفرد بحرية القول والعقيدة ويتحرر من الفزع والفاقة.

ولما كان من الضروري أن يتولى القانون حماية حقوق الإنسان لكيلا يضطر المرء آخر الأمر إلى التمرد على الاستبداد والظلم.

ولما كان من الجوهري تعزيز تنمية العلاقات الودية بين الدول،

ولما كانت شعوب الأمم المتحدة قد أكدت في الميثاق من جديد إيمانها بحقوق الإنسان الأساسية وبكرامة الفرد وقدره وبما للرجال والنساء من حقوق متساوية وحزمت أمرها على أن تدفع بالرقي الاجتماعي قدماً وأن ترفع مستوى الحياة في جو من الحرية أفسح.
\end{document}
```

MWE of not working \setotherlanguage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Common},PunctuationSpace=0,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Numbers={Proportional},SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},BoldSlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},SmallCapsFeatures={FakeSlant=0}]{Libertinus Serif}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,ItalicFont=*,Scale=1.75]{Scheherazade}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[short foobar]{long fooooobar}

some english text

\begin{arabic}
الديباجة

لما كان الاعتراف بالكرامة المتأصلة في جميع أعضاء الأسرة البشرية وبحقوقهم المتساوية الثابتة هو أساس الحرية والعدل والسلام في العالم.

ولما كان تناسي حقوق الإنسان وازدراؤها قد أفضيا إلى أعمال همجية آذت الضمير الإنساني، وكان غاية ما يرنو إليه عامة البشر انبثاق عالم يتمتع فيه الفرد بحرية القول والعقيدة ويتحرر من الفزع والفاقة.

ولما كان من الضروري أن يتولى القانون حماية حقوق الإنسان لكيلا يضطر المرء آخر الأمر إلى التمرد على الاستبداد والظلم.

ولما كان من الجوهري تعزيز تنمية العلاقات الودية بين الدول،

ولما كانت شعوب الأمم المتحدة قد أكدت في الميثاق من جديد إيمانها بحقوق الإنسان الأساسية وبكرامة الفرد وقدره وبما للرجال والنساء من حقوق متساوية وحزمت أمرها على أن تدفع بالرقي الاجتماعي قدماً وأن ترفع مستوى الحياة في جو من الحرية أفسح.
\end{arabic}

some more english text \textarabic{بِكُلِ تَأْكِيد}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for reading and for your time and consideration.

Comment: You must use `\begin{Arabic}` with uppercase A, \arabic is already defined (for counters) and so polyglossia can not take arabic for the environment.